# How to Read message from Jboss JMS Queue using IIB ESB Toolkit

Tags: jboss, jms, ibm-integration-bus

I am working on a small project in which I want to consume the messages from the Jboss JMS Queue using IIB Tool kit. Apologize me that I am a learner in IIB.

The scenario is as below.

The Linux server is where the JBOSS is running and the messages are available in a particular JMS queue.  I got IBM Toolkit installed on my laptop/machine and created an application and a flow.  I placed the JMSInput from the pallet and got confused on where to configure the connection properties like IP Address, port number, Jboss user, password etc...

[image]

The idea is to consume the messages that are available in Linux server using IIB.  Request some expert help on how to configure and achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The `jnp` based Initial Context Factory [seems like](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Remote%20JNDI%20Reference.html) not supported in JBOSS 7 anymore. I would use the one described in [Remote JNDI Lookup](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/development_guide/remote_jndi_lookup).

I never did an IIB integration with a JMS provider in JBoss, but I did it with a standalone ActiveMQ. There I created a [JMSProviders configurable service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn28736_.html), where I could configure IP address and port in the `jndiBindingsLocation` property like this:

```
mqsicreateconfigurableservice <BROKER> -c JMSProviders -o ActiveMQ \
   -n initialContextFactory,jarsURL,jndiBindingsLocation,connectionFactoryName \
   -v org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory,c:\Users\daniel\apache-activemq-5.11.1\lib,tcp://localhost:61616,ConnectionFactory
```

See [Securing JMS connections and JNDI lookups](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac28605_.html) how to enter user id and password.